# Declaring a property with no instance variable

Tags: objective-c

Since Xcode automatically adds a @synthesis now, how can I declare a property **without** an corresponding ivar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to implement the getter and setter and then it won't be automatically synthesised and an ivar automatically created.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface Obj : NSObject
@property NSString* str;
@end

@implementation

-(NSString*) str {
    //TODO:
    return @"sdfsdf";
}

-(void) setStr:(NSString*) st {
//TODO:
}

@end
```

Naming convention is simple:

getter has the same name as the property (in example it is str), setter must have set prefix, i.e. setPropertyName (first letter of property name is uppercase: setStr:)

You can also add attributes like atomic, retain, strong etc. but they will have no effect in case you're implementing properties yourself, but it's a good hint for the users of your class.